# SQL Query only returning results for first customer

Tags: mysql

My sql query only returns results for orders that belong to the first customer in the database. Where have I gone wrong?

```
SELECT orders.id, 
       orders.created_at, 
       orders.customer_id, 
       customers.firstname, 
       customers.surname, 
       customers.email, 
       customers.telephone, 
       customer_addresses.address_1, 
       customer_addresses.address_2, 
       customer_addresses.address_2, 
       customer_addresses.city,
       customer_addresses.county, 
       customer_addresses.post_code 
FROM orders 
INNER JOIN customers ON orders.customer_id = customers.id 
INNER JOIN customer_addresses ON customers.id = customer_addresses.id 
ORDER BY orders.id 
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Comment: Do the other customers have addresses ?

Comment: @Vatev the customers have a required address_id field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if all the customers have address_id as you mentioned in your reply to @ceyquem's answer, I think you are joining customer_address table on wrong column. It should be

```
SELECT orders.id, 
       orders.created_at, 
       orders.customer_id, 
       customers.firstname, 
       customers.surname, 
       customers.email, 
       customers.telephone, 
       customer_addresses.address_1, 
       customer_addresses.address_2, 
       customer_addresses.address_2, 
       customer_addresses.city,
       customer_addresses.county, 
       customer_addresses.post_code 
FROM orders 
INNER JOIN customers ON orders.customer_id = customers.id 
INNER JOIN customer_addresses ON customers.address_id = customer_addresses.id 
ORDER BY orders.id 
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Hope it works

Comment: My pleasure. :)

Answer (score 3):

If all your customers don't have a defined address, it might be the reason, try changing the JOIN operators as follows to test. Also, remove the limit condition at the end to ensure you can see all the result:

```
SELECT orders.id, 
       orders.created_at, 
       orders.customer_id, 
       customers.firstname, 
       customers.surname, 
       customers.email, 
       customers.telephone, 
       customer_addresses.address_1, 
       customer_addresses.address_2, 
       customer_addresses.address_2, 
       customer_addresses.city,
       customer_addresses.county, 
       customer_addresses.post_code 
FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN customers ON orders.customer_id = customers.id 
LEFT JOIN customer_addresses ON customers.id = customer_addresses.id 
ORDER BY orders.id;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, all the customers have an address_id.

Comment: yes the second customer is now being returned but the assigned address is not being recognized and joined, even though it works for the first customer.

Comment: so this confirms that you have a join issue in your address table, i think it is here:
customers.id = customer_addresses.id
should change to something like that (trying to guess your field names):
customers.id = customer_addresses.customer_id

Comment: This works, stupid error by me. Thanks again for the help +1